# How to download files in zip in php (yii)

Tags: php, yii, download, zip

How to download user uploaded files in php yii framework?

I have list of users on my website, every user can upload multiple files for each sections(Work Information, Education, Certificates etc)

The uploaded files are being saved in uploads files. Here is the link

```
C:\wamp\www\project\themes\mydesign\assets\global\uploads
```

in uploads foler, there are many other folders, folders are named with user id..

```
C:\wamp\www\project\themes\mydesign\assets\global\uploads\1\
C:\wamp\www\project\themes\mydesign\assets\global\uploads\2\
C:\wamp\www\project\themes\mydesign\assets\global\uploads\3\
```

1,2,3 is name of folder for user1, user2, user3.. and 1,2,3 is a `id` of user1, user2,  user3.

When user first upload anyfile and save it, then the folder for that user is created in uploads folders.

All users files are each section are saved in their folder.. Now I want to add a download button in CgridView near the delete button for each user.. and i want to download all the files in zip for any user i want.

Any example code of doing it? What tool, extension or library should i use? or is there any code available? im new to yii, have no idea how to get all files for each user and download in zip folder. any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:** You need to generate associate link in your grid to call a Yii controller -> action, let say actionZipDownload. For this, follow the link below:  Make sure you also pass the userId to that action.

> http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/593/yii-cgridview-add-custom-button/

**Step 2:** on that action based on passed userId you need target associate user directory path according to your setup (directory structure).

**Step 3:** Read all the files from that particular directory, add those for zip creation and store the zip file in a temporary directory. zip name can be userId_date.zip

The source probably for step 2 and 3 would be like below, you need to do some adjustment to the relative path as $destination. Also check php doc for http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php

```
<?php
public function actionZipDownload(){
$userId = $_GET['userId']; // get the passed user id
$zip=new Zip Archive();
$destination=dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])."/project/themes/mydesign/assets/global/uploads/".$userId."/filename.zip";
if($zip->open($destination,ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true) {
  return false;
}
 $doclist=CUploadedFile::getInstancesByName('files');
 foreach($doclist as $thefile)
 {
  $random=rand(11111,99999);
  $filename=$random.$thefile;      
  $zip->addFile($thefile->tempname,$filename);
 }
 $zip->close();   
 }
 ?>
```

**Step 4:** after successful generation of the zip, send the response to browser for download.

**Step 5:** After successful download you might need to delete the temp zip archive to save space.

> From step 2 to step 5, follow this link http://www.bsourcecode.com/yii-framework/yii-files/yii-zip-format/

Hope helps.

Comment: yeah, but how do i work on step 2,3? that is what im confused with, how will i get the files from upload folder for each user by their user id? as im new to yii, not sure how to start that! any sample code for this?

Comment: I try to write a sample code for step 2 and 3. you might to debug and do some adjustment to the script. let me know if this what you are looking for.

Comment: i do some modification in the code above, plz check again. did it worked?

Comment: also i which Yii version you are using?

Comment: im trying to check ur code right now. well this is download code but in user folder, there are many files, first we have to create Zip and then download but i don't understand what is that **uploads/".$userId."/filename.zip";** and how is this code creating zip. im updating my question with my edited code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111485/discussion-between-asfi-tanoli-and-syed-ekram-uddin-emon).

Comment: I have made some changes to the code and fix it according to my requirements, it is working, I was providing the wrong destination for saving zip files.

Comment: Gr8! please vote / mark the answer right, if it helps, the answer was to guide you, so that you can play around,  also vote  important comments that might helpful other users to understand the problem and get outcome quickly. you can also updated code, so that other user can vote the questions as well.